# Get DataRow if column names in a string array have matching values in a string array

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm trying to get a DataRow from a dtResult datatable if column name in [colName] list has a matching value as [grbByValue] list. my goal in the below code is to get [test1] and [test2] return datarow from dtResult and  should be the same as [update] (which is hard coded). but have issue in both test1 & test2. test1 has error and don't know how fix and test2 is returning null.

`rule` is a DataTable that looks like this:

[image: rule]

All the below logic is run for each row of `rule`.

`dtResult` is also a DataTable that looks like this:

[image: dtResult]

EDITED CODE

```
string[] grpby = { "ageband","gender","code"};
List<string> grbByValue = new List<string>() { "1","85+","1","1010"};

        DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc = dtResult.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
        dc.AutoIncrement = true;
        dc.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
        dc.AutoIncrementStep = 1;

        dtResult.Columns.Add("DataSourceID");
        dtResult.Columns["DataSourceID"].DefaultValue = "1";
        dtResult.Columns.Add("RuleID");
        dtResult.Columns.Add("GroupBy0");
        dtResult.Columns.Add("GroupBy1");
        dtResult.Columns.Add("GroupBy2");
        dtResult.Columns.Add("GroupBy3");
        dtResult.Columns.Add("GroupBy4");
        dtResult.Columns.Add("GroupBy5");
        dtResult.Columns.Add("Result", typeof(decimal));
        dtResult.Columns["Result"].DefaultValue = 0.00;


        var colName = (from a in dtResult.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                       where a.ColumnName.ToString().StartsWith("GroupBy")
                       select a.ColumnName).OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
        colName.Insert(0, "RuleID");
        colName = colName.GetRange(0, grbByValue.Count);

        //comment/UNCOMMENT below to test [test1]
        //DataRow z = dtResult.NewRow();
        //for (int i = 0; i < grbByValue.Count; i++)
        //{
        //    z[colName[i]] = grbByValue[i];
        //}
        //dtResult.Rows.Add(z.ItemArray);

        var distDtResult = dtResult.DefaultView.ToTable(true, colName.ToArray());
        bool exist = false;
        DataRow update = null;

        foreach (DataRow dr in distDtResult.Rows)
        {
            var row = dr.ItemArray.ToList();
            exist = row.SequenceEqual(grbByValue);
            if (exist == true)
            {
                //var test1 = (from t1 in distDtResult.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.ItemArray == dr.ItemArray)
                //             join t2 in (from m in dtResult.AsEnumerable()
                //                         select new
                //                         {
                //                             //ideally the below column list will be derived from [colName] dynamically
                //                             RuleID = m.Field<string>("RuleID"),
                //                             GroupBy0 = m.Field<string>("GroupBy0"),
                //                             GroupBy1 = m.Field<string>("GroupBy1"),
                //                             GroupBy2 = m.Field<string>("GroupBy2")
                //                         }) on t1.ItemArray equals t2.ItemArray
                //             select new
                //             {
                //                 t2
                //             }).FirstOrDefault();

                update = dtResult.AsEnumerable().Where(r =>
                                                r.Field<int>("id") == 1 &&
                                                r.Field<string>("DataSourceID") == "1" &&
                                                r.Field<string>("RuleID") == "1" &&
                                                r.Field<string>("GroupBy0") == "85+" &&
                                                r.Field<string>("GroupBy1") == "1" &&
                                                r.Field<string>("GroupBy2") == "1010").FirstOrDefault();


                break;
            }
        }

        if (exist == false)
        {
            DataRow a = dtResult.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < grbByValue.Count; i++)
            {
                a[colName[i]] = grbByValue[i];
            }
            dtResult.Rows.Add(a.ItemArray);

            var test2 = dtResult.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.ItemArray.Equals(a.ItemArray)).FirstOrDefault();
            update = dtResult.AsEnumerable().Where(r =>
                                               r.Field<int>("id") == 1 &&
                                               r.Field<string>("DataSourceID") == "1" &&
                                               r.Field<string>("RuleID") == "1" &&
                                               r.Field<string>("GroupBy0") == "85+" &&
                                               r.Field<string>("GroupBy1") == "1" &&
                                               r.Field<string>("GroupBy2") == "1010").FirstOrDefault();

        }
```

Comment: Can you include some sample input? It looks like it would be stored in `grpby` but that is not defined/populated in your snippets.

Comment: @B.Witter - i've added sample input.

Comment: I think that helps, but I am not sure it is clear what the expected output is given your ask and the code snippets provided. We don't see what `rule` is and we can only assume what `dtResult` and `dr` look like. That may be enough to get good answers for you =D

Comment: @B.Witter thanks for the suggestion. first timer here. hope it's better now.

Comment: No problem, we all start somewhere. I am trying to model this myself to see what we can do, but I am not sure what some sample rows of `dtResult` would be. And it seems that `grbByValue` is unused, is that intended?

Comment: It looks like `dr` is not going to have the Column `RuleID` on it because `colName` does not contain `"RuleID"` and you are limiting `distDtResult` to be only the columns from `dtResult` that are included in `colName`.

Comment: If my answer below solves your problem, please mark it as answer. Thanks!

Comment: @B.Witter - your answer below got me into different way of thinking. I'm modifying my whole approach to the problem. Will post my solution once i test all. but thanks a lot for taking the time to helping.

Comment: i just posted the edited code

Comment: The error you are getting in `test1` is due to the `select` returning an anonymous object, so it does not have an `ItemArray` property. It seems to me to be a bit tough to just make your own `DataRow` at that level, but I am not very familiar with `DataTable`s. The problem in `test2` may just be using `Equals` instead of `SequenceEquals`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a good starting point, at least to better ask questions and move towards an answer.

```
string[] colName = { "RuleID", "GroupBy0", "GroupBy1", "GroupBy2" };

// "All the below logic is run for each row of rule"
// this goes through each row of the rule DataTable
foreach (DataRow rule in ruleTable.Rows)
{
    // This is going to be equivalent to the grpby variable you specified
    var groupRules = rule.Field<string>("GroupBy").ToString().Split("|");

    // Some sort of mapping may need to go here to go from "ageband" to "GroupBy0", "gender" to "GroupBy1", etc.

    foreach(DataRow row in dtResult.Rows)
    {
        DataTable distDtResult = dtResult.DefaultView.ToTable(true, colName);

        var updateTEST = from dr in distDtResult.AsEnumerable()
                         where dr.Field<string>("RuleID") == rule["RuleID"].ToString()
                         && dr.Field<string>("GroupBy0") == row["GroupBy0"].ToString() // ageband
                         && dr.Field<string>("GroupBy1") == row["GroupBy1"].ToString() // gender
                         && dr.Field<string>("GroupBy2") == row["GroupBy2"].ToString() // code
                         // more
                         select dr;
    }
}
```